# How to encrypt IDClient with SAS

Tags: encryption, sas

We have a DMP project, in which  I have to send to Adobe our client ID to manage cross device. But our DPO want us to encrypt this ID. By 256-bits rules. RSA.
I'm using SAS (9.3) to generate the files. Is there a way the encrypt this ID.
the file will have more data than the ID : eg : sex, age, ....

File sample :

```
ID;Age;Sex
12345;45;M
```

Want something like

```
ID;Age;Sex
nAca0Pb6bH1cQRfkO9wReQTmLqZYz+R5OT/bjBOv5uQ#;45;M
```

Thanks,
jérôme

Comment: Will the recipient need to decrypt the ID ? Will you be getting back results with the encrypted ID, that you then need to decrypt ?

Comment: The encryption is only for the transfert. No need to decrypt for the recipient. But I would like to keep the "matching" in my database in order to archive this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mask the transmitted data values of specific variables by using encrypting functions -- either `MD5` or `SHA256HEX`

Sample code

Each row in the `class` table is given a unique `id` value, and that value is masked with an encryption function.  The id to masked id cross reference is saved in a separate table for posterity.

```
data want(drop=id) masks(keep=id id_masked:);
  set sashelp.class;
  id + 1;
  id_masked_md5 = md5(cats(id));
  id_masked_rsa256 = SHA256HEX(cats(id), 0); 
run;
```

Comment: Sorry. My version of SAS is    `Custom version information: 9.3_M2`

Comment: I got this error `ERROR 68-185: The function SHA256HEX is unknown, or cannot be accessed.`

Comment: What version of SAS are you using ?  SHA256 is part of SAS 9.4M3.  Your DPO might have to accept MD5 masking or update your SAS license.